# users -> proxy -> proxy -> smart contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts

I'm writing smart contract for Ethereum using Solidity and OpenZeppelin. I wish to implement this kind of situation

[image: this kind of situation]

Where I deploy a proxy for each user and a proxy uses the same smart contract with the storage of the proxy.

But I have not found the examples about it.

The unique example are this:

```
const func: DeployFunction = async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  const Box = await ethers.getContractFactory("BoxV1")
  console.log("Deploying Box, ProxyAdmin, and then Proxy...")
  // In order to use UUPS we have to manually specify so with the option kind: 'uups'.
  const proxy = await upgrades.deployProxy(Box, ['hash'], { initializer: 'initialize', kind: 'uups'})
  console.log("Proxy of Box deployed to:", proxy.address)
};
```

where I deploy the proxy with box. But I have not found the way to deploy the proxy alone and to link the proxy to the smart contract.

The goal is:

I have a smart contract that store a hash. I have 5.000.000 of user. I wish to give at each user the same smart contract. But one day I could update this smart contract, so I wish to do one or two transaction in order to update it. I thinks that I have to use the proxy but I have not found an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "beacon" proxy is what you're looking for. Basically you can deploy multiple proxies that point to the same implementation. The address of the implementation is saved in a contract called Beacon. The owner of the Beacon can call it to upgrade the implementation, changing all the proxies in a single transaction.

To start:

```js
const Box = await ethers.getContractFactory("BoxV1");

// deploy the beacon and implementation
const beacon = await upgrades.deployBeacon(Box);
await beacon.deployed();
console.log("Beacon deployed to:", beacon.address);
```

To deploy a proxy:

```js
// deploy a proxy
const box = await upgrades.deployBeaconProxy(beacon, Box, [42]);
await box.deployed();
console.log("Box deployed to:", box.address);
```

To upgrade the implementation:

```js
// change implementation to new version
const BoxV2 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BoxV2");
await upgrades.upgradeBeacon(beacon.address, BoxV2);
```

Docs:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/hardhat-upgrades#beacon-proxies
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy#BeaconProxy